# On click to assign a value

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to use the `onclick` event to assign an integer to a mutable variable (a running scorecard).

The idea is, the user will click on a button and depending on their choice of button, the `onclick` event will update the variable `runningTally` with a value.

My code inserts the value to the HTML page but it automatically inserts the total of ALL the possible values, not just the values from `onclick`.

I've tried rewriting the code multiple ways and have not succeeded. Could anyone offer some help?

```
var one = document.getElementById('1');
var two = document.getElementById('2');
var btn = document.getElementById('showtally');

let runningTally = 0;

function score(points) {
    runningTally += points;
    document.getElementById('showtally').innerHTML = runningTally;
};

one.onclick = score(5);
two.onclick = score(4);
```

Comment: Why are you mixing usage of var and let in the same scope?  If the data is all global then I would use var for everything.  I don't think your set-up of onclick is correct, you don't do it that way, you specify a function to call when the event is raised but you can't pass it a parameter like that.  See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: You are missing a `)` here : `document.getElementById('showtally'
.innerHTML = runningTally;`

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the eventlisteners like this:

```js
let runningTally = 0;

function score(points) {
  runningTally += points;
  document.getElementById('showtally').innerHTML = runningTally;
};
```

```html
<button id="1" onclick="score(5)">1</button>
<button id="2" onclick="score(4)">2</button>
<div id="showtally"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign functions anonymous like this

```js
var one =  document.getElementById('1');
var two = document.getElementById('2');
var btn = document.getElementById ('showtally');

let runningTally = 0;

function score(points) {
  runningTally += points;
  document.getElementById('showtally').innerHTML = runningTally;
};

one.onclick = function(){score(5);};
two.onclick = function(){score(4);};
```

```html
<button id="1">1</button>
<button id="2">2</button>
<label id="showtally">0</div>
```